# FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My chat application crashes with the above error when its time to display notifications

```
class MyFirebaseMessaging() : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    lateinit var message:Notification.MessagingStyle.Message
    val KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply"
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
    override fun onMessageReceived(mRemoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d("notif","called 1")
        super.onMessageReceived(mRemoteMessage)

        val sented = mRemoteMessage.data["sented"]
        val user = mRemoteMessage.data["user"]
        val sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val currentOnlineUser = sharedPref.getString("currentUser", "none")
        val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        if (firebaseUser !== null && sented == firebaseUser.uid) {
            if (currentOnlineUser !== user) {
                sendOreoNotification(mRemoteMessage)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH)
    private fun sendOreoNotification(mRemoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val user = mRemoteMessage.data["user"]
        val body = mRemoteMessage.data["body"]
        val name = mRemoteMessage.data["name"]

        Log.d("notif","called")
        val replyLabel = "Enter your reply here"
        val remoteInput = RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
            .setLabel(replyLabel)
            .build()


        val j = user!!.replace("[\\D]".toRegex(), "").toInt()
        val intent = Intent(this, HelperActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        bundle.putString("userid", user)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)


        var i = 0
        if (j > 0) {
            i = j
        }
        val oreoNotification = OreoNotification(this)
//        if (!appInForeground(applicationContext)) {



            val icon_ = Icon.createWithResource(applicationContext,
                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)


            val replyAction = Notification.Action.Builder(
                icon_,
                "Reply", pendingIntent)
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build()

            val userP = android.app.Person.Builder().setName(name).setKey(user).setIcon(
                    Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher)).build()



              message = body?.let {
                  Notification.MessagingStyle.Message(
                      it,
                      Date().time, userP)
              }!!
            Log.d("notif","recieved :${message.text}")

            val style = Notification.MessagingStyle(userP).addMessage(message)


            val builder: Notification.Builder =
                oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(pendingIntent, replyAction, style)
            Log.d("notif","$body")
            oreoNotification.getManager?.notify(i, builder.build())

//        } else {
//            oreoNotification.getManager!!.cancel(i)
//        }


    }



    private fun appInForeground(context: Context): Boolean {
        val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val runningAppProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses ?: return false
        return runningAppProcesses.any { it.processName == context.packageName && it.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND }
    }

}
```

OreoNotification.kt file

```
val getManager  :NotificationManager? get() {
        if(notificationManager==null){
            notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        }

            return notificationManager

    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun getOreoNotification(pendingIntent: PendingIntent?,replyAction:Notification.Action,style: Notification.Style)
            :Notification.Builder{

        return Notification.Builder(applicationContext, OreoNotification.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle("Vcare")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(replyAction)
            .setStyle(style)
    }
```

Logcat of the crash

```
2020-09-25 23:54:32.658 7896-8031/com.example.vcare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-Messaging-Intent-Handle
    Process: com.example.vcare, PID: 7896
    java.lang.RuntimeException: User must be valid and have a name.
        at android.app.Notification$MessagingStyle.validate(Notification.java:6690)
        at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:5573)
        at com.example.vcare.notifications.MyFirebaseMessaging.sendOreoNotification(MyFirebaseMessaging.kt:105)
        at com.example.vcare.notifications.MyFirebaseMessaging.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessaging.kt:39)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:85)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.passMessageIntentToSdk(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:55)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleMessageIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:34)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.handleIntent(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:23)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService.lambda$processIntent$0$EnhancedIntentService(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@20.2.4:43)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.EnhancedIntentService$$Lambda$0.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This line seems to be erroneous according to logcat (kt:105)

```
oreoNotification.getManager?.notify(i, builder.build())
```

the app crashes as soon as i send a message from another device and its time to display notifications.

What is this supposed to mean?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: User must be valid and have a name.
```